# Image overflow within bootstrap span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of spans in a row.  Within each span I have an image that is bigger than the span.

Currently the image's width gets set to the width of the span.  What I'd like to do is make the image be it's full width, with the overflow hidden.

Can someone let me know how to make an image within a span be it's original width, not the width of the span??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The span probably has a max-width set for img inside of it to 100%. Try overriding that style with:

`[class*="span"]img {
     max-width: auto !important;
 }`

Or something similar.